# Force line break after inline-block element using CSS

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to make a simple form. As an example, this is what I'm trying to get it to look like.
[image: example]

This is the current architecture for each field:

```html
<p>
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input></input>
</p>
```

I struggle once I get to the CSS part. Here's a full example, and any help would be greatly appreciated

```css
div {
    text-align: center;
}

form p {
    display: inline-block;
}

form label {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <form>
        <p><label>Name:</label> <input type="text"></p>
        <p><label>Password:</label> <input type="text"></p>
    </form>
</div>
```

I just cannot figure out how to get a line break after the input with the current CSS.

Comment: replace inline-block with table for p element? (and margin:auto to center)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can use `float` instead of `inline-block`

```css
form {
    max-width: max-content;
    margin: auto;
}

form p {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: the content will no more be centred

Comment: I missed, fixed.